# PowerBI dataset and Excel on Mac OS

Tags: excel, macos, powerbi

I want to provide access to data from a DataWareHouse to several users of my company. I need to create a dataset with filtered data and then I want to provide to granted users access to those data inside Excel on Mac Os.
I don't know if this is possible as the feature "Analyze on Excel" is not available for download on Mac Os.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Connection to the Power BI datasets via Power Query, can't be done on Excel for MacOS as it is not supported. Power Query for MacOS Excel is limited to csv, json and d few others. Power Pivot for MacOS isn't available.

You can connect to OLAP sources like SQL Server Tabular using this paid for [option](https://www.cdata.com/kb/tech/ssas-odbc-mac-excel.rst), but only for On-premise SSAS, or Azure Analysis Service. If you have Power BI Premium, the CDATA plugin might be able to connect to the xmla endpoint of the dataset.

The other option is create the filtered data model with PBI Desktop on Windows and deploy it to the service, then to give them access to the Power BI Service. The user can then create their own reports, or export the data via csv, but the export size it limited to 100,000 rows.

For Mac users Power BI is mostly limited to viewing/creating the reports in the service.